ebpf verifier: R3 invalid mem access 'scalar'
when wrote an ebpf prog, I had encountered a problem which produce R3 invalid mem access 'scalar' 
my verifier log is：
; if (hash_policy->policy_specifier_case == ROUTE__ROUTE_ACTION__HASH_POLICY__POLICY_SPECIFIER_HEADER) {
    1172: (61) r1 = *(u32 *)(r3 +24)
    R3 invalid mem access 'scalar'

policy_specifier_case is enum type of hash_policy, which include __u32 integer.
type of hash_policy is:
struct  Route__RouteAction__HashPolicy
{
  ProtobufCMessage base;
  Route__RouteAction__HashPolicy__PolicySpecifierCase policy_specifier_case;
};

Thanks help of everyone!

That isn't enough of the verifier log to tell you exactly what is going on. It says that you are trying to deference a non-pointer value. So its likely that hash_policy comes from a map lookup and you didn't do a null check or you constructed hash_policy from some source the verifier couldn't identify as a memory pointer. Please add more of the log if that isn't enough to fix your issue

@Dylan Reimerink As you said, the prog that I wrote trying to deference a non-pointer value, I want to know why it happend.

As Dylan said, we can't tell without a lot more verifier logs.
